# Piñata files not being found

Tags: nft, ipfs, pinata

I have uploaded two folders, one with .mp4 files and one with .png files. The name of each file ranges from 1 to 10000.

But for some reason I can't access the files with this link pattern:
ipfs://[ipfsFolder1]/1.mp4 or ipfs://[ipfsFolder2]/1.jpg

I receive the following error:

`ipfs resolves -r /ipfs/[ipfsFolder1]/1.mp4: no link named "1.mp4" under [ipfsFolder1]`

I found out that the files are on this link
ipfs://[ipfsFolder]/%20[tokenId].mp4

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"%20" is an escape code that represents a space. So perhaps the mp4 was saved a with a leading space in front of the digit.